# Alternatives to "exponentially bigger"

Tags: idiom-requests

One idiom that grinds my gears is "[exponentially](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/exponentially) bigger" outside of an actual (exponential) trend, e.g. in pairwise comparisons like "A is exponentially bigger than B".

What is a good idiom for expressing the idea that one thing is much much larger than another in a qualitative sense?

Some examples

> Guys have a level of insecurity and vulnerability that's exponentially bigger than you think. With the primal urge to be alpha comes extreme heartbreak. The harder we fight, the harder we fall.
>   Read more at: http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/j/johnkrasin442337.html

> [Torchlight II promises To Be Exponentially Bigger Than Original](http://wegotthiscovered.com/gaming/torchlight-2-promises-exponentially-bigger-original/)

> [Stephen A. Smith: If Serena Williams Were White, Her Exposure Would Be 'Exponentially Bigger and Better'](http://www.breitbart.com/video/2015/09/08/stephen-a-smith-if-serena-williams-were-white-her-exposure-would-be-exponentially-bigger-and-better/)

Comment: A is orders of magnitude bigger than B.

Comment: I think an example sentence with realistic concepts instead of A & B would help.

Comment: I had not seen this expression being abused in this way. Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: What's wrong with replacing _exponentially_ with _much_? (as in: _Torchlight II promises to be much bigger than original_)

Comment: @JR. Like it! You could even add a 'very' if you wanted to go up a notch. Not likely to catch on though ;-)

Comment: [**"IT'S OVER 9000!"**](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/its-over-9000), might be a suitable candidate.

Answer (score 2):

When you say "bigger", you are comparing 2 magnitudes.
When you look at 2 points representing these magnitudes in a Cartesian plane, absent any other points, you can't tell what the rule is for getting from the first to the second. Was it simpy addition? Multiplication? Exponentiation?
When you tell me to imagine 2 such points, and tell me the 2nd is exponentially bigger, all I can  say for certainty is that the 2nd is bigger than the first. but I have no way of knowing how much bigger. It could be bigger by a very small amount, and still lie on an exponential curve the other one lies on too.
So if you want to say *much bigger*, say that. If you wanted to say tens or hundreds or thousands of times as big, say one of those. If you're just trying for hyperbolic effect, say something like *humongously bigger* and your hearer will know you're not committing to any specifics.

Comment: Tried to find the meaning of 'humongously' using the dictionary on my iPhone, but I got 'no definition found'. What language is it, exactly?

Comment: @David humongous, Merriam-Webster  http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/humongous:  very large.

Comment: @ab2 — Well it's nice somebody knows what it means. But would you recommend its use?

Comment: @David I first heard humongous at MIT decades ago.  I would use it in informal conversation only, but I am a rather formal person.  I haven't heard the adverb, but that doesn't necessarily mean it isn't used.  I agree with Schor:  I'd say "orders of magnitude larger".  I upvoted your question and also frank's answer because he explained so well why "exponentially larger" is meaningless.

Comment: @ab2 Thanks for the upvote. Come to think of it, *humongous* came into the language with the Mutant Ninja Turtles so we're both showing our ages. But I was looking for an informal way of saying "much, much bigger" to convey an impression rather than a number. *Orders of magnitude* works fine, especially for something that really can't be measured. I mean, can you really say a *level* of some attribute is *bigger*?